Can you tell me how can i replace posts from blog in below screenshort
Can you tell anyone how can i replace posts from blog in below screenshort. I have working on Avada theme and always i see an posts in place of blogs. can you tell me how to resolve this issue.


You mean the word 'Posts' in the line at the top? That looks like it's the Avada Breadcrumbs element, so your best bet would be to ask Avada for help directly.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
